# How to list number of users

Tags: bash, xubuntu

How do I specifically list the **number** of local users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `getent passwd | wc -l`, `compgen -u | wc -l`, `wc -l < /etc/passwd` there are some examples.

Comment: `mapfile -t < /etc/passwd; echo ${#MAPFILE[@]}` think this is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you what. If you want all local users, including system users, then it's just the list in `/etc/passwd` so:

```
wc -l /etc/passwd
```

will give you the total number.

Perhaps you prefer to exclude users who have `false` or `nologin` set as their shell? In that case:

```
grep -vE 'false|nologin' /etc/passwd | wc -l
```

(you can run that command without the `| wc -l` to see if it looks like the list you'd expect)

Comment: You can count matches with `grep -c`

Comment: @bac0n you can indeed, but I think it's a good idea to introduce the idea of pipes fairly early on :)

Answer (score 0):

Most folks know of compgen as something you can use to list things like the aliases available to you. Such as:

```
compgen -a
```

Or to list the commands that are available to you:

```
compgen -c
```

However, it can also be used to list the number of users:

```
compgen -u
```

From there, you can just count them with the `wc -l` that you also see in the other answer.

```
compgen -u | wc -l
```

That will give you a total number of users. Like many things in Linux, there's all sorts of ways to get the information you need. If you want to look fancy, you can even use grep and regular expression.

```
compgen -u | grep --regexp="$" --count
```

That looks pretty fancy, but the "$" just signifies the end of a line and then you're telling it to count them.